# Openrasta Validators Issue

Tags: c#, rest, openrasta

I am facing a strange issue with Validators in OpenRasta.I have entry in my configuration file for Validator

```
ResourceSpace.Uses.CustomDependency<IValidator<Customer>, CustomerValidator>(DependencyLifetime.PerRequest);
```

I am testing my API using REST Client.While making a call to my API method in handler, validator is not getting called every time.I feel that i am making some mistakes in my configuration.

Can anybody let me know what needs to be done for fixing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changed Dependency Lifetime from PerRequest To Transient for both ResourceValidationInterceptor and CustomerValidator as Follows.

```
ResourceSpace.Uses.CustomDependency<IOperationInterceptor, ResourceValidationInterceptor>(DependencyLifetime.Transient);

ResourceSpace.Uses.CustomDependency<IValidator<Customer>, CustomerValidator>(DependencyLifetime.Transient);
```

that solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled a pipeline contributor to intercept and perform validation?

Seeing your full configuration and handler code sample would help.

Comment: I have a ResourceValidationInterceptor which has a entry in configuration file

`ResourceSpace.Uses.CustomDependency<IOperationInterceptor, ResourceValidationInterceptor>(DependencyLifetime.PerRequest);`

Please let me know if you want more details.